# Can't or Couldn't??

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

i want to ask what's the difference between these sentences. Because Can't is present tense and happened is past tense. Could anyone explain it to me thank you!

1. She Can't believe what happened to her.
2. She Couldn't believe what happened to her.

Answer (score 2):

"What happened to her" is an event in the past, but her "inability to believe" that event (meaning her astonishment at it) may be either present (*She can't believe it = She is astonished at it now*) or past (*She couldn't believe it = She was astonished at it then*).

Comment: i thought you can't have two tenses in one sentence?

Comment: @Finn Sure you can. "I went to town yesterday and I'll go again tomorrow."